# Selecting all values from a table in mysql using a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table called Contacts with a field called person_id that I have connected to a java application.

If no value is specified for person_id in the application, I want to select everything from the contacts table using a stored procedure.

The operation I want to perform is this:

```
Select * from Contacts where (person_id like "%")
```

For this I have written a stored procedure shown below:

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectTest2`(In p_id int(11))
BEGIN
    if p_id = null then
        set p_id = "%";
    end if;
    select * from Contacts where (person_id like p_id);
END $$
Delimiter ;
```

However when I run this procedure in my sql using the following

```
call selectTest2(null)
```

The table that is returned is blank. How do I make it show all the values in the table?

The parameter p_id gets its value from a text box in the application. If the user has entered an id, I want the procedure to show only that particular record else I want it to show all records.

What have I done wrong and how do I correct it? I am aware that p_id is an int however I tried the same thing with other fields of type varchar and the table failed to return any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **case statement** in **where clause** like below

`WHERE CASE WHEN p_id IS NOT NULL THEN person_id = p_id ELSE TRUE END`

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you this worked. However I am still interested in knowing why my code did not work. Do you have any idea why my code returned an empty table?

Comment: In your code, try changing `if p_id = null then` to `if p_id IS null then` and let me know if that does not work.

Comment: it does not work for p_id since it is an int however it works for other fields that are of type varchar. Thank you for your answer.